# Single-user mode not allowing write access

Tags: terminal, mount, single-user

I'm trying to copy some files from Single user mode to an external USB but I'm having trouble. I can't use the terminal in another account because it's not an administrator account and it's not in the `/etc/sudoers` file. I need `sudo` because these files contain the password for a specific user who forgot their password. The path for these files are `/Volumes/<hard drive name>/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/<username>.plist`. I need to mount my usb first to actually put the files in the drive. To do that, I need to make a new directory and mount the drive there using the `mount` command. But for some reason, even after I run `/sbin/mount -uw`, I still get an error saying that the root filesystem is read-only. Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm running Single User mode on Mac OSX 10.6.8.

Comment: What permissions does this user account have? If you have administrator access, can you try changing them?

Comment: Excellent edits. +1 If I can dig up my notes on that OS I’ll post if I can recall the command to mount an external. I’m thinking even if the / is read only you can mount a second OS drive as RW to make changes to the user database files.

Comment: Sorry guys, I made a syntax error. I was typing `/sbin/mount -uw` instead of `/sbin/mount -uw /`. The computer didn't know what directory to mount because I didn't specify one!